# Error (Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256) while uploading file to s3 server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nodes

Error message : The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

Angular js http post request

```
 url: 'https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
       method: 'POST',
           data: {
              key: file.name,
              AWSAccessKeyId: '*****',
              acl: 'private',
              Policy: $scope.policy,
              Signature: $scope.signature,
             "Content-Type": file.type != '' ? file.type : 'application/octet-stream', // content type of the file (NotEmpty)
              file: file
```

Nodejs(signature and policy are sent to scope variable in angular js)

```
var secretKey = '*******';
var s3Policy = {
    "expiration": "2018-12-01T12:00:00.000Z", // hard coded for testing
    "conditions": [
        { "bucket": "*****" },
        ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
        { "acl": "private" },
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
        {'x-amz-meta-uuid': '14365123651274'},
        {'x-amz-credential': '****/20181212/eu-west-3/s3/aws4_request'},
        {"x-amz-algorithm" : "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
        ["content-length-range", 0, 524288000]
    ],
};
var stringPolicy = JSON.stringify(s3Policy);
var base64Policy = Buffer(stringPolicy, "utf-8").toString("base64");
var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", secretKey)
    .update(new Buffer(base64Policy, "utf-8")).digest("base64");
var s3Credentials = {
    s3Policy: base64Policy,
    s3Signature: signature
};
```

How this issue can be resolved? I have tried all possible methods but it is not working.

Comment: Anyone into it?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing and matching elements from Signature V4 and Signature V2.  They are incompatible algorithms.

Your policy looks like V4, but your signature and the form you are posting are both V2.  AWS4-SHA256-HMAC is Signature V4, and the error message indicates that your bucket is in a region that supports *only* V4... so your code needs to all use V4 logic.

Review https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html